# How do I build a timer that executes some code in intervals?

Tags: c#

I have an application where it is possible for the user to schedule some taske. A task could be to "send email", "execute application" etc. Each of these tasks has a start time, and this varies. Some of these tasks should run from the start time of the task to the stat time of the next task.

My question is how do i build a timer that will allow this to happen. Usually i would do this using a backgroundworker and an infinite loop - then check the time and the schedules each second or so. The problem with this approach is that when i close my application, the background worker is not closed.

Any ideas on a better pattern for this timer, or for solving the thread issue?

Comment: What about Quartz? http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/. You can also implement Windows Service: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. What's more, you can hang around Windows Task Scheduler: http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/

Comment: As suggested by @pwas, don't reimplement something which has already been done for you, +1 for the Windows Task Scheduler

Comment: Yeahm true, for anything else. But some of the tasks to do are visual (display video, audio, images) and they need to loop throughout the time interval assigned to them. And based on the result from a webservice it is possible to change this behavior, and the timeframes. All that is already built into my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your BackgroundWorker approach, but you have to correctly handle the application termination.
In the BackgroundWorker, you probably have something like:

```
while (true)
{
    ...
}
```

Try changing in

```
while (!myBackgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
{
    ...
}
```

and add something like

```
myBackgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
```

when the user quit your application.